# Automatically opening the keyboard in Codename One

Tags: android, keyboard, codenameone

I need to automatically open the numeric keyboard to facilitate entering an access PIN. I've tried giving focus to the textfield (textField.requestFocus();), but it hasn't worked.

I tried:

```
Display.getInstance().editString(textField.getText(), Display.INPUT_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

Without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textField.startEditingAsync()` or if it's a new form that you're showing use `form.setEditOnShow(field)`.

Comment: It's work! thank you Shai!